# Where can I download for free the entire price history of the nasdaq composite and s&p500 indices?

Tags: equities, time-series, index, nasdaq

I would like the entire price history of both these indices at an end-of-day level, not intra day. Is there an R api that I can use for such an exercise?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the Nasdaq on the following website:

https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/NASDAQCOM

Not sure how accurate the data is though.I also found S&P data here:

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EGSPC/history?p=%5EGSPC

Comment: Fred is a government service that is considered accurate, and is used by many professional economists in their work. I would be more suspicious of advertiser supported sites like Yahoo.